# mongodump , mongorestore , mongoimport and mongoexport

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport, mongodump, mongoexport, mongorestore

Among mongodump , mongorestore , mongoimport and mongoexport which one isn't required to run against a running mongod or mongos . I've refereed to the documentation it says mongodump, mongoimport and mongoexport require a running mongod or mongos but there is nothing mentioned about mongorestore.

Can someone help with this.

Comment: It seems like an odd question, may I ask why you care? There's really not a valid use case to use **any** of them without a running mongod to run them against. A long time ago you could run mongodump against a dbpath, but that's no longer the case.

Comment: I came across this question while taking the mongodb DBA cetification exam two weeks ago. I was wondering why this question apperead on the test which was for mongodb 3.2 when the functionality to run against 'dbpath' is is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Every command related to mongoDB (mongo, mongodump, mongofiles, mongooplog, mongorestore, mongosniff, mongotop, mongod, mongoexport, mongoimport, mongoperf, mongos, mongostat) requires a mongod instance to manipulate task.

If you run theses commands without any running mongod instance, you will got:

```
couldn't connect to [127.0.0.1] couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017
```